# Visual studio 2019 giving error when I try to install nuget package file offline

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have setup a folder on my pc for local nuget packages that I have downloaded

When I click install in package manage without internet connection I get this error

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request. 
The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'
```

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Sources**

uncheck `nuget.org` package source.

[image]

**Since** you have aligned the network connection and checked nuget.rog, VS will visit all checked package sources.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings`, and remove the package source pointing to NuGet.org
You still have this source in your package source list and NuGet is going to try and connect to it.